# I don't want to open my already closed app while I use my another develop app

Tags: android, background, nfc

I have my code here, it will be opened in background(or closed) when tag any NFC

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.nfc_rfid_rw.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
              <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
              <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED">
                </action>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

        </activity>
    </application>
```

My question is when I use this app to scan any NFC it will not open my app, I want to do the same, I don't want to open this app which will open in background when I use another app(my develop app).

This app I used won't open my app(not my develop app)

[image]

app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc&hl=zh_TW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in this project https://github.com/nadam/nfc-reader

In `onCreate`, it had `PendingIntent`, like follow:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

onResume:

```
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
```

After define this in my app, every app I developed will never jump to my first app(or choose what app I want to use), I can only use the foreground app!!